# Google Sheets Formula for a range of answers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Trying to figure out a formula to automatically grade based on a range - for example, if the answer (number) in Column C is between...

```
70 - 94 = WTS
95 - 115 = EXS
116 - 140 = EXC
```

Sample data in column C:

```
76
96
95
123
115
```

I'd assume I'd put the formula in column D to get the outcome based on the range - so if the answer is between 70 and 94 I want column D to recognise this and put the response WTS. Following the rest of the ranges, I want to be able to use this formula for all data in the column.

Here is a link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tLzm5u4tvWtDtNSxlN5COrkIm8w10_kyi7oobSzG5v8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75016055/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 2):

Use `XLOOKUP()` function.

```
=XLOOKUP(C2,{70,95,116},{"WTS","EXS","EXC"},"",-1)
```

To spill results dynamically use `XLOOKUP()` with `MAP()` function.

```
=MAP(C2:C6,LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP(x,{70,95,116},{"WTS","EXS","EXC"},"",-1)))
```

To refer full column as input try the following.

```
=MAP(C2:INDEX(C2:C,COUNTA(C2:C)),LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP(x,{70,95,116},{"WTS","EXS","EXC"},"",-1)))
```

[image]

Comment: And this is for static input range `=INDEX(XLOOKUP(C2:C6,{70,95,116},{"WTS","EXS","EXC"},"",-1))`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

`=MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(C2:C),1,LAMBDA(r,c,VLOOKUP(INDEX(C2:C,r),INDEX({--REGEXEXTRACT(G:G,"^\d+"),REGEXEXTRACT(G:G,"[A-Z]+$")}),2,1)))`

-

[image]